# How to improve VueJS Vuetify performances

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 3 `v-select` components, with only a few items (10!), but each `v-select` takes approximately 300ms to render. It seems quite a lot for 30 items.

Here is the performance report I got:
[image]

My code is quite simple:

```
<v-select
        style="cursor:pointer"
        :items="options"
        single-line
        class="pt-0"
        append-icon="keyboard_arrow_down"
        :value="value"
        multiple
        chips
        @change="updateSelect">
      </v-select>
```

If I remove the multiple option (then removing the checkboxes), it takes 150ms.

Is it something we should consider as "normal"? If no, any idea on how to improve these performances?

Comment: is it possible your inline styles create a larger render time? I usually use single file components or globally-included Sass

Comment: Unfortunately removing the style property doesn't change anything